# Unable to load the requested class: Template

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a project using Codeigniter and Bootstrap. When I'm trying to use Bootstrap as template I get this error.

> Unable to load the requested class: Template

here's my controller :

```
public function cek_login() {
        $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
                        'password' => substr(md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE)), 0, 8)
            );
        $this->load->model('m_login'); // load model_user
        $hasil = $this->m_login->cek_user($data);
        $sess_array=array();
        if ($hasil->num_rows() == 1) {
                foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess_data) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_data);
                $job = $sess_data->job;
                $check = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            }
            if ($job =='admin') {
                 $this->template->load('admin/static','admin/dashboard');
            }
            else 
                if ($job=='Doctor') {
                    $this->template->load('member/static','member/index');
            }       
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('Gagal login: Cek username, password!');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
    }
```

I have set up my library in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('template','database','session','form_validation');
```

Is there anything that I forgot to set up?

Comment: What is the `template` library you are using? Is it available on github? If not, you should post the relevant code for it, or a reference to it.

Comment: Also, please read this about md5 hashing passwords: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Comment: @Alex i just using bootsrtap and make it as template, do I need to set up n how?

Comment: @Alex if I call a index function from other controller that have the same page to load using link localhost/dentalrecord/c_member/index ,  it will load successfully using code in index :  $this->load->view('member/static');$this->load->view('member/index');

Comment: @Alex if I call an index function from other controller that have the same page to load using link localhost/dentalrecord/c_member/index ,  it will load successfully using this code in index function :  $this->load->view('member/home');$this->load->view('member/index');   . But when I using that code to load the page after login as a doctor, delete 'template' in library in autoload.php, the css cannot load in the page. How can this happen?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't follow

Answer (score 4):

Usually load errors are due to files not being in the right place, in your case `Template.php` (first letter *has* to be capitalized) not being in `/application/libraries` OR the file `Template.php` not having a declaration like `class Template` (again, first letter *has* to be capitalized).